# how to scroll the scrollbar automatically in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have linked the data with the scrollbar in excel and want to scroll the scrollbar automatically instead of by mouse. Please let me know if this can be done.

Answer (score 2):

This VBA scrolls down one row at a time:

```
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = ActiveWindow.ScrollRow + 1
```

Comment: You can also write `ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = Range("A100").Row` or replace the `Range("A100") with some type of variable.